# How to correctly use XmlWriter.Create()?

Tags: c#

I have a method that perfectly serialize data for me:

```
public static string Serialize(BackgroundJobInfo info)
{
    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var writer = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
        var dataContractSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(BackgroundJobInfo),
                                                                null,
                                                                int.MaxValue,
                                                                true,
                                                                true,
                                                                new MySurrogate());
        dataContractSerializer.WriteObject(writer, info);
        return stringWriter.ToString();
     }
}
```

But as Microsoft [recommend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) I need to use `XmlWriter`.

So I change one line:

```
var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter);
```

And everything broken - `Serialize()` return empty string (instead of string that contains xml)

`MySurrogate` contains a method

```
public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType)
{
    var maskedProperties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
    var setToNullProperties = maskedProperties.Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataMemberAttribute), true).Any() &&
                                                         m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DoNotSerializeAttribute), true).Any());
    foreach (var member in setToNullProperties)
    {
        member.SetValue(obj, null, null);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

How to correctly use `XmlWriter` and fix my problem?

Comment: What do you mean everything is broken? What is broken exactly? If you don't use `XmlWriterSettings` in `XmlWriter.Create` a default writer will be created without indentation and with strict error handling, newline normalization, etc.

Comment: I mean `Serialize()` return empty string instead of string with xml

Comment: You probably need to flush it.

Comment: @SLaks Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: He means you should call `writer.Flush` before the end of the `using` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `Flush()` to force the XmlWriter to actually write the text to the underlying TextWriter.

Comment: Like this: `var writer = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter); writer.Flush();` ? or after `dataContractSerializer.WriteObject(writer, info);` ?

Comment: Flushing before you write any content won't do anything.

Comment: When I `Deserialize` and create  `var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);` should I do some stuff like `flush()`?

Comment: See the documentation.  `Flush()` flushes the writer's buffer; that doesn't make any sense for a reader.